# static eth network bridging in ubuntu 13.10

Tags: ethernet

I have two static `eth` networks(`eth1` and `eth4` ) in ubuntu 13.10, how I can I bridge the two networks,ie I need to access `eth4` by using `eth1`

My static configuration:

```
auto eth4 eth1

iface eth4 inet static
    address 10.4.8.45
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 10.4.8.254

iface eth1 inet static

    address 192.168.1.100
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.168.1.254

auto lo
 iface lo inet loopback
```

Comment: [This](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NetworkConnectionBridge) might be helpful.

Comment: 13.10 is outdated and no longer supported for over 2 years now. You should upgrade to a supported release (14.04 or 16.04) as soon as possible or do a reinstall. Don't forget to back up your data before that though.

Comment: Correct answer is to update your release so everyone would stop yelling at you. Incorrect answer is you got two separate subnets, bridging only works on one subnet. So you either need to make everything on one subnet, or you make your box a router and forward traffic between two subnets  by uncommenting `net.ipv4.ip_forward=1` in your /etc/sysctl.conf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TL;DR from https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NetworkConnectionBridge.

1. Install `bridge-utils` package.

   ```
   sudo apt-get install bridge-utils
   ```
2. Add the following text to the end of `/etc/network/interfaces` file.

   ```
   # Bridge between eth1 and eth4
   auto br0

   # [Dynamic IP]
   iface br0 inet dhcp

   # [Static IP] For static configuration delete or comment out the above line and uncomment the following:
   # iface br0 inet static
   #  address 192.168.1.10
   #  netmask 255.255.255.0
   #  gateway 192.168.1.1
   #  dns-nameservers 192.168.1.5
   #  dns-search example.com

   bridge_ports eth1 eth4
   bridge_stp off
   bridge_fd 0
   bridge_maxwait 0
   ```
3. Restart networking.

   ```
   sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart
   ```

Explanation:

- `auto br0`: This sets up a new interface called `br0` which represents the bridged networks.
- **[Dynamic IP]** `iface br0 inet dhcp`: IP of this network (the bridged network) is obtained using DHCP.
- **[Static IP]** `iface br0 inet static`: In this case you should un-comment its following commands.
- `bridge_ports`: interfaces to be bridged.

Comment: @HiI'mFrogatto: He's running an EOL release so unless he's set it to get packages from the archived repository, then your package installation line won't work for him.

Comment: of-course  just downloaded bridge-utils_1.5-2ubuntu6_i386.deb is it ok ? :)

Comment: In trouble :( configured as above, but i need static ip for eth4 too ..